# pgfgantt "title list options" incompatible with beamer

Tags: beamer, pgfgantt

Creating a Gantt chart using the `pgfgantt` package, with days of the weeks as the titles, can be done using `title list options` as demonstrated in the package manual. But it doesn't seem to agree with `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{ganttchart}[x unit = 3em]{7}
\gantttitlelist[title list options={var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x using "\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\y}"}]{0,...,6}{1}\\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
! Use of \\gantttitlelist doesn't match its definition.
\kernel@ifnextchar ...rved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                  #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
l.11 \end{frame}

? x
```

Is there any workarounds?

Comment: @percusse Very succinct solution! I think that deserves to be made into an answer.

Comment: cybersingularity kindly agreed to add the missing details for me.

Comment: @percusse cybersingularity Excellent, thank you both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same problem occurs using the `article` class with the `translator` package, the latter being loaded by `beamer`.

The macro `\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname` wraps its output in a `\translate`, which with `translator`'s definition, does not appear to be safe in an expansion only context, the latter being the context in which `evaluate` for `\foreach` is executed.

There are a number of workarounds. Here's a couple:

- The simplest, suggested by percusse, is to add `\noexpand` before `\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname`.
- Alternatively (my original answer), one can reset `\translate` to behave like `\@firstofone`, which is what `pgfcalendar` sets it up to be when the `translator` package is not loaded (modulo `\long`).

  Workaround code in the context of the MWE:

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  %\documentclass{article}
  %\usepackage{translator}
  \usepackage{pgfgantt}
  \usepackage{pgfcalendar}

  % by putting \resettranslate in a macro, we avoid issues with directly placing a \renewcommand or \makeatletter in beamer's frame environment
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand{\resettranslate}{\let\translate\@firstofone}
  \makeatother

  \begin{document}


  \begin{frame}
  \begin{ganttchart}[x unit = 3em]{7}
  \resettranslate
  \gantttitlelist[title list options={var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x using "\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\y}"}]{0,...,6}{1}\\
  \end{ganttchart}
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
  ```

  For clarity, I have kept the patch local within the `ganttchart` environment. This means one needs the patch for every `ganttchart` environment unless one is prepared to change `\translate` document-wide (e.g. by executing `\resettranslate` immediately after its definition).